# Como identificar adequadamente se uma frase é exclamativa?

Tags: gramática, pontuação

Eu tenho um certo problema com o uso de exclamações, mas como nunca me aventurei com longos e importantes textos isso nunca foi um problema.

Mas quando trabalhando com transcrições audiovisuais (*captioning*) isso começou a me incomodar porque, como as pessoas e personagens das cenas muitas vezes demonstravam muita euforia, falando rápido, de forma enérgica e até mesmo atropelada, praticamente todas as sentenças terminaram com uma exclamação.

Mas em Português não falamos ou escrevemos assim e, por isso, eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de identificar ou caracterizar uma frase como sendo REALMENTE exclamativa para, assim, pontuar adequadamente.

Comment: "Mas em Português não falamos ou escrevemos assim", como não? As vezes acontece de falar atropelando palavras. Se o teu problema é individuar frases exclamativas em textos sem pontuação, dubito que exista uma maneira bem definida de o fazer.

Comment: Se você puder oferecer uns exemplos, acho que se tornaria mais fácil para nós ajudarmos. Mas tenha em mente que, se estas transcrições com as quais você trabalha são de natureza artística, elas estão fadadas a utilizarem representações emocionais e sentimentais com frequência, e é importante que a língua as transpareça. Seja com o uso da exclamação, seja com o uso de figuras de linguagem, ou mesmo com o uso de um vocabulário mais expressivo (por exemplo, `horroroso` em vez de `ruim`, ou `súbito` em vez de `rápido`), elas precisam aparecer no produto final.

Comment: Eu estou revisando todas as transcrições, uma a uma, observando entonação vocal, expressões faciais e até mesmo arqueadura toráxica das personagens pra ver se elas estão falando de uma forma mais entusiasmada que o normal ou não e, assim, removendo gradualmente parte das exclamações. Vai ser um trabalho quase que por instinto, infelizmente...

Comment: Não existe tal maneira. Eu posso dizer: "Ganhei um milhão de dólares!!". Mas nada me impede de dizer "Ganhei um milhão de dólares.". O uso da exclamação está ligado a alguns fatores: emoções, tom da voz, uso de ironia, etc.

Comment: Aliás, uma frase exclamativa bem escrita virá com o sinal de exclamação.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto sim, é mesmo algo de instintivo. Há um motivo para a pontuação existir: na palavra escrita substitui aquilo que é a linguagem não-verbal e entoação presente na oralidade, entre outros propósitos.

Answer (score 2):

A exclamação, ao meu ver, pode ser usada de duas maneiras que são bastante relevantes - além de outras maneiras diferentes.

Assim como disse o Peixoto, se você está definindo tom de voz pode usar a exclamação como indicador de diversos sentimentos (surpresa, emoção, decepção, etc.)

Já no caso de estar trabalhando com avisos, notificações, propagandas, etc. A exclamação deve ser utilizada de outra maneira. Nesses casos, ela deve pontuar aquilo que é "destaque", ou seja, aquilo que chama a atenção.

Em um aviso técnico e/ou formal você dificilmente verá uma exclamação, justamente porque todas as informações contidas nesse texto são importantes e nenhuma deve chamar mais atenção do que a outra, porém se você trabalhar com anúncios publicitários ou jornalísticos, por exemplo, a Exclamação ressalta aquilo que é mais importante no texto. Por exemplo.

**Texto técnico**

> A oliveira é uma árvore típica da costa mediterrânea e exige uma grande luminosidade e um clima caracterizado por invernos suaves, outonos ou primaveras chuvosas e verões secos e quentes.

Perceba que as informações são dispostas de maneira igual, sem caráter de importância.

**Já um texto publicitário (estilo Casas Bahia)**

> Hoje na Loja X encontre o preço mais baixo! Guarda-roupas por R$ 300. É só hoje!

Vejam que foram exclamadas duas sentenças que são de importância: o apelo para o 
**preço baixo** e para a **data da promoção (só hoje)**.

Basicamente, a exclamação dá mais destaque às frases que são consideradas "chaves" e podem incluir caráter de urgência ou sensação de algo que necessita de atenção.

Espero ter contribuído.

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo, pode verificar o tipo de pontuação conforme o tipo de frase (interrogativa, afirmativa, imperativa ou exclamativa).

Desconheço qualquer outra forma de demonstrar essas formas que não seja através de pontuação. Se está fazendo um *captioning* (que acredito que seja a transcrição do que está sendo dito para a TV), deve procurar em padrões já utilizados por essa industria (no meu entendimento está off-topic dessa discussão). Porém vou tentar ajudar, já vi tons de vozes sendo declarados entre conchetes **[Sussurrando]**. Dessa forma, acredito que deva usar o mesmo padrão, por exemplo **[Exclamando]**, **[Xingando]** e assim por diante. 
Essa mesma recomendação foi o que vi nesse guia de *captioning* que pode ser acessado [aqui](http://captioning).

Sei que disse que quase todas as falas são em tom exclamativo. Se é realmente isso, deve ser um padrão dessa conversa e daí não sei o quão relevante será essa informação.

> Saiba o que são e como identificar os tipos de frases interrogativas,
>   declarativas, imperativas e exclamativas. Vejamos exemplos:
>
> Frases interrogativas
>
> A frase interrogativa expressa uma pergunta, um pedido de informação
>   ou de esclarecimento sobre algo e até uma bronca, uma recriminação.
>   Termina com ponto de interrogação.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> Será que ele vai conseguir a classificação?  Você sabe por que Mariana
>   não veio hoje à praça? Frases declarativas
>
> A frase declarativa expressa uma declaração afirmativa ou negativa a
>   respeito de algo. Termina com ponto-final.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> Eu estou com a palavra agora. (afirmativa). Mariana não passou pela
>   praça. (negativa). Frases imperativas
>
> A frase imperativa expressa uma ordem, um pedido, um convite. Pode vir
>   com ponto-final ou ponto de exclamação.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> Mariana dê o ar da graça, por favor! (pedido).  Coma, agora, todos os
>   bombons. (ordem). Frases exclamativas
>
> A frase exclamativa expressa surpresa, emoção. Termina com ponto de
>   exclamação.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> “Todo mundo comete erros, Helga!” (emoção).  Oh... que tristeza,
>   Helga!! (decepção). Exercícios Tipos de Frases com Gabarito

[Fonte](http://www.gabarite.com.br/dica-concurso/83-frase-interrogativa-declarativa-imperativa-e-exclamativa)

Answer (score 0):

Quando o sentido da frase demonstra medo, admiração, estranheza, exclamação, por isso o uso do simbolo (!) . Também quando o sentido é intuitivo sentir que algo foi uma exclamação.
Em casos em que o autor esquece de inserir o ponto de exclamação, note-se pelo sentido da frase. Em caso de fala (oral) seria um engano alguém exclamar sem entoar a forma da frase como exclamação!
[enter link description here](https://www.normaculta.com.br/ponto-de-exclamacao/)
[enter link description here](http://www.mundodamonografia.com.br/revisao-como-usar-exclamacao/)
Para saber mais:
[image]
[image]
[image]